# Why do we need the event StreamSocketListener.ConnectionReceived when we use SocketActivityTrigger?

Tags: sockets, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

StreamSocketListener is used in UWP Apps to make the App act like a Server, i.e. listen on a network port and respond when it receives a connection on that port. Thus, we assign a handler to the event ConnectionReceived which is invoked whenever a connection is received.

And as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/network-communications-in-the-background), when we want to make this possible when the app is suspended as well, we configure a background task that is triggered using a SocketActivityTrigger whenever a connection is received. Thus, the process happens in the Run method of the background task in this case. So does this mean, that we don't need to assign a ConnectionReceived event handler anymore when SocketActivityTrigger is used?

Answer (score 0):

> Why do we need the event StreamSocketListener.ConnectionReceived when
>   we use SocketActivityTrigger?

There's a difference between the two. The StreamSocketListener acts like a Server, when your app connects to the listener, the `StreamSocketListener.ConnectionReceived` event will be triggered. You can get the connected socket in it and send data to it.

But about SocketActivityTrigger, when your app receives data on a socket, a keep alive timer expired or the socket was closed, the Run method will be triggered.